# Rails 4 asset pipeline losing vendor assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, capistrano, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I can't seem to figure out how to make sprockets find assets in `vendor/assets`.  I've ben been pushing off the problem by adding all of my assets to `app/assets`, but it's becoming way too cluttered.

I have read the documentation, and tried adding all of the following lines to my `application.rb` file.

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/*"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/fonts"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/stylesheets"
config.assets.precompile << Proc.new { |path|
  if path =~ /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)\z/
    true
  end
```

They work locally, but when I push them to the server, none of my vendor assets are there.  I'm using capistrano for deployments, and I know that there were some issues with the upgrade.  That could be the root of the problem, but I followed the documentation to get it deploying (almost) everything alright.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be me being stupid, and quick to jump the gun on other problems.  I dove too far down the rabbit hole, and lost sight of what was happening.  I did not include the `otf` filetype in the regex, and it wasn't being included.

*Facepalm*

**EDIT:**

To clarify: all I had to do was change

```
if path =~ /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff)\z/
```

to

```
if path =~ /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|otf)\z/
```

Comment: can you share what the solution was in the specifics, rather than the abstract for the noobs? ^^

Comment: @gwho: specifics added to the answer

Answer (score 0):

When you run `rake assets:precompile` are you manually setting the env to production?

The command should read:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`