# FontAwesome icons not shown in Rails when deployed to Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, font-awesome

I have tried the solutions in many other related StackOverflow questions, but my deployed app still shows a **white rectangular** box, instead of the icons. On localhost it runs OK.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.2'

gem 'protected_attributes' 
gem 'font-awesome-sass'
...
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3' # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
end

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

group :production do
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_serve_static_assets'
end
```

**application.css**

```
*= require font-awesome
```

I have precompiled assets, and modified my **application-xxx.css** file (according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19663344/how-to-deliver-fonts-from-a-non-standard-directory-using-asset-pipeline)) as follows:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: font-url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: font-url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),       font-url('/assets/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff'), font-url('/assets/fontawesome- webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), font-url('/assets/fontawesome- webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

my **production.rb** contains

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

When I load the app, there's no error on the console BUT the fonts are not loaded as a resource:

[image]

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**
Problem solved, I'm afraid I had not read the console messages when I ran

```
rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

[image]

I had some invalid CSS which for some reason in `localhost` didn't matter but in production did. By the way, I switched to `gem "font-awesome-rails"`.

Comment: try [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails)

Answer (score 0):

Well heroku compiles your css to sass and they gave a tool http://css2sass.herokuapp.com/ that can help help you convert your css to sass.

to get the **gem "font-awesome-rails"** into your app you can follow the instructions in [font-awesome-rails](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) remember that is really important to include the css file in `application.css` like

```
 /*
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

wish you the best. and hope that this helps